# StackOverflow answering details

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

Does this site have a bug like you ask a question, then answer it yourself and mark your answer as the best one and get 15 points for free?

Comment: Post this on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: This is covered in the FAQ.

Comment: In the context of meta it seems incorrect that this question should have been down voted. However, the brazen attempt to test the theory below is more deserving of the down vote. :o)

Answer (score 4):

You can't accept your own answer right away - you have to wait for a couple of days.

If you *do* [accept your own answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), you don't get the 15 point bonus.

Of course, you could use two accounts to cheat - but expect people to spot this pretty quickly.

Answer (score -1):

Likely it really has. But there are doubts.