# Etiquette of answering a question in anticipation of it being moved

Tags: discussion, etiquette, migration

I've just answered a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012479/stackoverflow-answering-details-closed) after voting for it to be closed as "belongs on meta". It was [moved to meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34666/stackoverflow-answering-details) very shortly afterwards, as anticipated.

Does anyone have a problem with my behaviour here? I thought it was a perfectly reasonable question for Meta, and it was almost *certain* to get moved here - so I thought I might as well get a head-start on answering it while it was still on SO.

Personally I think this is in line with the "fastest gun in the West is a feature, not a problem" approach, but I'd like to know if anyone is particularly offended before the same situation comes up again :)

Comment: In all honesty, you're overthinking this. I can't see how anyone can lose from this.

Comment: My personal policy is to vote to move, start to write the answer, and wait quite a bit. If it's in a quiet hour and it doesn't get moved in  one or two minutes, I'll post the answer on SO. Otherwise, I'll wait and post it on the other site. I'll post the answer immediately if there's already an answer posted (like in your case).

Comment: I'd say the only possible problem here would be if your answer on SO was not transfered to meta - as far as I'm concerned, the more information, the merrier.

Comment: It's a good way to get upvoted twice!

Comment: On a recalc the rep from the answer on SO will be lost.

Comment: Sounds perfectly reasonable to me Jon.

Comment: I must say I feel somewhat happy that I just went to ask a question and noticed that Jon Skeet had already asked the same thing I was about to ask!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as your answer is good, I can't see how it might hurt. The rep you potentially gain from the answer should be moved along with the question to the other site, the question gets a good answer and it spares you the need to go from one place to another.

Comment: +1 - agreed. Also, the questioner has a greater chance of seeing your answer if it appears briefly before the question is migrated. I sometimes wonder how obvious the link to the migrated question is, so anything that helps users see answers before their question gets migrated is good.

Comment: A lot of people are still struggling with the concept of migration. Seeing answers before it gets moved maybe spurs them to find the question on the site it's been moved to.

Answer (score -1):

You're Jon Skeet. You are the standard!

Comment: This was a serious question. Why not offer him a serious answer?

Comment: I am being serious. Jon has asked "I'd like to know if anyone is particularly offended before the same situation comes up again". Clearly Im not. I agree with his reasoning. Do i need to write an essay to convince him of that?

Comment: It did sound a bit glib, though....